# OpenIDConnect provider's HTTPS certificate doesn't match configured thumbprint

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, openid-connect, github-actions, openid

[image: githubActions connection to aws credential]

```
- name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          role-to-assume: ${{secrets.ARN_GITHUB_ACTIONS_ROLE_UAT}}
          aws-region: ${{secrets.AWS_REGION}}
```

Here is where I got the error and I don't have access to access cloud trails to see the history,it's possible that someone changed the credentials or delete the role?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that GitHub (accidentally) updated their thumbprint recently, so the result is now 6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1

More details here
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-13-github-actions-update-on-oidc-based-deployments-to-aws/

Answer (score 13):

There was a new change in the thumbprints, take a look at this blog post:

https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-27-github-actions-update-on-oidc-integration-with-aws/

> Customers experiencing issues authenticating via OIDC with AWS should [configure both thumbprints to be trusted in the AWS portal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html).
> The two known intermediary thumbprints at this time are:
>
> ```
> 6938fd4d98bab03faadb97b34396831e3780aea1
> 1c58a3a8518e8759bf075b76b750d4f2df264fcd
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You shuld update your Thumbprints in AWS.
In this link you can find how to create your thumbprints. [Obtaining the thumbprint for an OpenID Connect Identity Provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html).
After that

- Go to your [IAM Identity Providers](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iamv2/home?region=us-east-1#/identity_providers/)
- Choos your provider
- Manage Thumbprints
- Update the thumbprint with the one you optaind following the Obtaining the thumbprint for an OpenID Connect Identity Provider